# Does an Asp.Net MVC project want to be the whole application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I like Asp.Net MVC, I just want to be aware of what the designers of it intended as I work in it.

Is it trying to say "*hey, here's a place for your business logic. Don't worry about a seperate BIZ dll. All your layers can just go in this project. Got your one stop shopping right here!*"?

Maybe another way to ask the question is, when you look at Asp.Net MVC projects written by others, do you see the "Model" part being used in lieu of seperate business logic (BIZ) and domain model components?

Another aspect of the same question is, if you have multiple UIs planned (website, mobile app, windows app, service), do you have to fight (go against the tool / do something other than the offered default way of doing things) the Asp.Net MVC project to wrest out control of the business logic? And take care as you go that it doesn't creep back in?

This is not a rhetorical question. I don't have a bone to pick, and I see this as a factual question, not one soliciting opinions. Either it is or it isn't. It's designed for whatever it's designed for; I just don't know what that is, but I need to be aware of it as I go.

Comment: MVC itself is agnostic of the layers you are describing.  Many of the _templates_ do put repository/business logic in the same project, but that doesn't mean that you have to _keep_ it there (or use those templates).

Comment: Uh, no?  Nope?  Nah?

Comment: @DStanley, by templates, you mean Asp.Net MVC templates that you can add to that project by "Add New Item"?

Comment: Among others, yes.  Keep in mind, though, that you don't _have_ to use those templates - you can build your repositiries in other projects (there are even templates that do _that_ for you), and use _those_ in your MVC project.  The out-of-the-box RAD template, however, do make architecture concessions in favor of simplicity.

Comment: @DStanley, ok go ahead and mention those in an answer (and maybe what they do or how they offer business logic), and I'll mark it as the answer. Fastest answer ever :)

Comment: @DStanley, two things I notice is, the model folder, and the default project which contains business logic (`AccountModels.cs`)

Comment: It has been said that MVC is more of a user-interface pattern and not an application architecture.

Comment: @Matthew, that is true, but the Asp.Net MVC implementation apparently, by default, locates the M in that pattern in the same component (project). My question is about the component model really, which is orthogonal to the pattern involved.

Comment: The way I treat ASP.NET Mvc models is as view models just to move data to and from the view.  Entities would live in their own library and would not be sent to the view directly.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks. I might be confused about how to use it then,  because the way you use "models" sounds like the way I would think I should use a `Controller`, since the controller supposedly sits between the `View` and the `Model`. Are you saying that you connect your model class to the view without going thru the controller, or are  you saying that your model is a *projection* of your domain model custom tailored for that view?

Comment: Projection, check out auto-mapper, it would be a good thing to use for the tedious projection work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC itself is agnostic of the layers you are describing. Many of the templates do put repository/business logic in the same project, but that doesn't mean that you have to keep it there.

You also don't have to use those templates - you can build your repositories in other projects (there are even templates that do that for you), and use those in your MVC project. The out-of-the-box RAD templates, however, do make architecture concessions in favor of simplicity.

I would do a search in NuGet for "MVC templates", play around with some of them, and see if there are any that architect things more in line with your desires.

Comment: You said *"The out-of-the-box RAD templates, however, do make architecture concessions in favor of simplicity"*. So, I wasn't hallucinating; there was something to my question. @downvoter / closers, I don't understand the reaction, but oh well.